# ListActivity inside Tabs is not updating

Tags: android, android-listview, listactivity

I have a ListActivity inside a TabHost which works fine when it gets created. But when the this activity pauses and is resumed, the ListView is blank. Here's my code so far:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_aulas_agendadas);

    dh = new DataHelper(getApplicationContext());

    mMessageListView = getListView();

    cursor = dh.selectAulasAgendadas();
    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    mAdapter = new MessageAdapter(this, cursor);
    mMessageListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

MessageAdapter extends CursorAdapter, because I need to group the results by using a header.

I've tried to move the cursor initialization to the onResume method, with no luck.
When I press the back button and the Activity gets created again, it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent more than 2 days trying to solve it. I ended up putting android:noHistory="true" on the Activity that contains the TabHost. I know is not the correct solution, but it worked.